# Differentiability of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|x-r_n|}{2^n}$ at rational points on $(0,1)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $\{r_1,r_2,r_3,...\}$ be an enumeration of rational numbers in $(0,1)$ and consider the function. i.e. $\{r_1,r_2,r_3,...\}=(0,1)\cap \mathbb Q$

$$f(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{|x-r_n|}{2^n}.$$

It is easy to see $f(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable at every irrational point, $(0,1)-\mathbb Q$. But what about its differentiability at $\{r_1,r_2,r_3,...\}$?

At first sight, this might look indifferentiable at rational points, since at $x=r_n$ for example, the left and right derivatives of the term $\frac{|x-r_n|}{2^n}$ differ by $2\times \frac{1}{2^n}=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$. But the behavior of the rest of the sum seems to be very unpredictable, since in any neighorhood of $r_n$, there are infinitely many rational points and the signs inside the absolute values vary a lot. I am even speculating that for certain enumeration of $\{r_1,r_2,r_3,...\}$, $f'(r_n)$ *could exist*. Or one could ask, for a certain enumeration, how many $r_n$ are differentiable points of $f(x)$?

Even if the derivative at any rational points doesn't exist for any enumeration, this is still hard to prove.

Comment: Write $f(x)= \frac{|x-r_n|}{2^n} +\mbox{rest}$. Use the same idea of showing differentiability at irrational points to show that "rest" is differentiable at $r_n$.

Comment: @NickS Oh no, this seems to be a stupid question which should be on MSE...

Comment: Related is [Points of differentiability of $f(x) = \sum\limits_{n : q_n < x} c_n$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/249635/15780). FYI, I think I have a folder with many relevant papers in it, and I've been hoping to one day return to my answer there and extend it beyond the generalities given there, but thus far I have not gotten around to doing this (requires my having sufficient interest to do this when I also have sufficient spare time to do this).